# How do you call the something.function(parameters) notation?

Tags: c++, syntax, expression

I really don't know how to explain this neither to a browser nor to stackoverflow, so i'm going to just type an example.

```
vector<int> x;
x.push_back(5);
```

How do you call the fact that i used a dot to tell the function which vector i wanted it to operate with?

I tried googling it with no luck. I have no programmer friends to explain this to in person.

Comment: If you want to learn C++ good sources are : [a recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or from [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) that site is decent and pretty up to date.
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) for reference material (and examples). When you have done all that keep using [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with the latest best practices since C++ keeps evolving.

Comment: You really need to find a decent textbook to learn the basics of C++. The concepts to answer your question are covered early on in most (even bad ones) introductions to C++. No point in using SO for such basic learning (SO is not an introductory site - it's for people who already know the basics to ask specific questions). You won't have much luck with google unless you do a specific search - which you won't be able to do well before you know the basics.   If you had any competent programmer friends, they would have learned using a decent introductory text, and would advise you to do the same.

Comment: `.` is sometimes called the *member access operator*. But `->` is also sometimes called the same thing.

Comment: I think bulug's question makes it perfectly clear that he understands what the quoted code does. He just want to know what the operator is called.

Comment: I am actually studying from principles and practice of programming by stroustrup, i was left with this doubt because he introduces vector manipulation through functions but does not say how the dot thing is called. I thank you all for the resources, and clarifications you’ve provided. This community is a blessing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.` operator is a [member access operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) called the "member of object" operator. With this operator, you can access all data members and member functions of the class. In this case, you are accessing the [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) member function of the class and you are calling it.

The `()` is the [function call operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_function_call_operator). It can be applied to both non-member functions (i.e. functions that do not belong to a class) and member functions.

Answer (score 2):

The combination of

```
something.function(arguments)
```

is called a *member function call*.